# JPA NamedQuery does not pick up changes to modified Entity

Tags: jpa, flush

I have a method that retrieves Entities using a `NamedQuery`. I update a value of each entity and then run another named query (in the same method and `Transaction`) filtering by the old value and it returns the same Entities as if I had not changed them.

I understand that the `EntityManager` needs to be flushed and also that it should happen automatically but that doesn't make any difference.

I enabled hibernate SQL logging and can see that the Entities are *not* updated when I call flush but when the container transaction commits.

```
EntityManager entityManager = getPrimaryEntityManager();
MyEntity myEntity = entityManager.find(MyEntityImpl.class, allocationId);
myEntity.setStateId(State.ACTIVE);
// Flush the entity manager to pick up any changes to entity states before we run this query.
entityManager.flush();
Query countQuery = entityManager
        .createNamedQuery("MyEntity.getCountByState");
// we're telling the persistence provider that we want the query to do automatic flushing before this
// particular query is executed.
countQuery.setParameter("stateId", State.CHECKING);
Long count = (Long) countQuery.getSingleResult();
// Count should be zero but isn't. It doesn't see my change above
```

Answer (score 1):

To be honest I'm not that familiar with JPA, but I ran into similar problems with Hiberate's session manager.  My fix was to manually remove the specified object from Hibernate's session before querying on it again so it's forced to do a lookup from the database and doesn't get the object from cache.  You might try doing the same with JPA's EntityManager.

Answer (score 0):

I've just had the same issue and discovered two things:

- Firstly, you should check the FlushMode for the persistence context
  and / or the query.
- Secondly, make sure that the entity manager is
  exactly the same object for both transaction management and query
  execution. In my case, I had Mockito spy on the entityManager, which
  was enough to break the transaction management.